# Field doesn't have a default value

Tags: joomla-4.x, extensions

I have just migrated from Joomla 3 to Joomla 4 and have an issue in Ignite Gallery.

When I try to upload a new image, I receive the following error message:

`Upload Error, Adjusting the uploader settings in the component options -> upload tab may help, response from server: Field 'hits' doesn't have a default value`

I have checked the upload settings in the component options and these all seem fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this error using phpMyAdmin to change the structure of the [database-table-prefix]_igallery_img table so the "hits" field has a default value of "NULL" instead of "None".